# Use HTTPS client to send request to the port 440 on the server

Tags: java, linux, security, https, port

I want to send request

openssl s_client -connect server:440 < commands.text

to port 440 using a HTTPS client.

I have no idea what HTTPS client is or how to send the request.
It would be help if you could let me know the steps to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explaination :**

HTTP is just text. Request are in plain text, Response are in plain text too at least for headers.

HTTPS is just HTTP over SSL.

So the HTTP client is just  you. Once you are connected through SSL, just type text formatted as HTTP request like  :

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
```

It will request the page /index.html of the server. The server will likely close the connection if you type too slow, so copy paste the line instead of typing manualy.

**What to do ?**

I imagine you do not want to learn HTTP protocol and doing things in such a low level. But with openssl you just establish a connection with the server.

What you want is a software that will connect over SSL, generate a request for you, and display the server's response, i.e an HTTP client. You can try :

- [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)
- [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Anyway, whatever you plan (to manualy write HTTP Request or to use curl), you should learn a bit about [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP), and different types of Request (POST, GET etc.)